# Google php client library sample app does not work on PHP 5.3.25

Tags: google-api-php-client

I used the code from the sample app (https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php) on a server with PHP 5.4 and that worked just fine. Turns out the code just won't work on the production server which has PHP 5.3.25. The sample app does not run on it. The page (http://beta.magicmarks.in/google/signin.php) does not load

Chrome console shows an error 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

My gut feeling is that it's just that the library requires PHP 5.4 or higher. But then I tried it on two other servers with 5.3.20 and 5.3.3 and they worked fine. The requirements stated here are 5.3 or higher so i guess 5.3.25 should be supported. I'm quite clueless what's wrong. I've tried enabling the curl extension as well.

Upgrading the PHP on production server is a long process so that's my last resort if nothing else works.

Thanks.

Comment: did you check the webserver logs? can you load any other php page?

Comment: No haven't checked any logs, Could you tell me what logs to check? All other php pages work fine.

Comment: depends on your webserver/os, if it's Apache on Linux, I think the default location of the error log is /var/log/apache2/. If there's nothing there related to the script, you might want to use a debugger to see if/where the script is failing